# VB.NET bit shift confusion

Tags: vb.net, binary, bit-shift, shift

I have some questions regarding VB.NET bit shifting. I understand the `<< >>` operators are bit shift operators in VB.NET.

I have a two-byte hex value, `0x3ACC`, and each bit in these two bytes represents either a day, month or year. The bit structure of this hex value is `yyyy yyym mmmd dddd`.

I am confused as to how I should bit shift these values so that year, month and day are in their own `UINT16` values. What should the shifting numbers be and do I need to add any padding to the shift?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're going to need to use `And` as well as the bit shifting operations to get your result. You need to shift right (count the "non-year" bits for the amount) to get just the year. To get the day, just `And` with the value  that has all the "day" bits set. Extracting the month will require a combination of the two techniques, either `And`ing then `>>` or `>>` and then `And`ing with the correct mask.

---

Spoilers:

- To extract the year: `0x3ACC >> 9`
- To extract the day: `0x3ACC And 0x001F`
- To extract the month: `0x3ACC And 0x01E0 >> 5`

Comment: Thank you that has helped me so much! I understand completely now.